# Where and in what context did Guido van Rossum say "If you want your code to run faster, you should probably just use PyPy."?

Tags: python, pypy

[PyPy's main page](http://pypy.org/) states that Guido van Rossum has said:

> If you want your code to run faster, you should probably just use PyPy.

PyPy's home page does not refer as to where or in what context this statement has been made. Did he say that in a conference, a face-to-face talk with someone? What was the surrounding topic anyway? Was it about the performance of Python?

Comment: Even the submit button event has warned me about "This may be subjective.". I have quick-googled this statement but could not find a resource so far. I thought "Maybe I should ask to a mailing list of Python." but then I thought it is best-fit here since Google indexes this platform a lot, which might help Googlers like me. If it is suited to another StackExchange platform, which I could not find, moderators are free to close the question or migrate it to that platform. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems legit to me. It's objectively answerable.

Comment: It may be answerable, but it doesn't seem to be on-topic. This site is supposed to answer practical questions related to programming -- what difference does this make?

Comment: 100% off-topic question. If not, tomorrow I will ask something like "One guy said that <language> sucks, where and in what context did he say it?".

Comment: Interesting question, but sadly I think it is off-topic (Questions asking us to recommend or find a [...] off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow [...]). But I don't know if there is a more appropriate site for this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is basically a (interesting) trivia question.  Asked as “what program types benefit most/least from pypy perf gains?”, I’d support it, though I expect it we’d then get ‘opinion-based’ flagging.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's from his talk on type hints at PyCon 2015: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2wDvzy6Hgxg&t=16m52s